# Express.js logs error to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having the most odd of problems. In one of my controllers I throw an error using the following snippet

```
next(new NotFoundError('User not found'))
```

For some reason I'm getting the error logged to the console, not really knowing why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having looked over the code a handful of times, I realized that the problem came from not exiting the function after calling `next(err)`.

This code

```
next(new NotFoundError('User not found'))
```

Should be

```
return next(new NotFoundError('User not found'))
```

Notice the return statement before the function call.